# Git bash / Neovim not working

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

I'm trying to get Neovim to work in Git bash. When I type `nvim` in cmd, everything works as expected and it opens Neovim, when I do the same in the Git bash, the whole editor just turns blank until I CTRL+C out of it. I suppose that there might be some pathing problem, but I'm not sure. I attached some images as well.

I've tried to add the path to Neovim in gitconfig in the Git folder and in the home folder as well.

`which nvim` gives: `/c/Program Files/Neovim/bin/nvim`

[image: image1 - Gitbash]

[image: image2 - Gitbash]

[image: Cmd - works]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: try to use `winpty nvim`

Answer (score 3):

Got it working and found two solutions.

1. Reinstall bash and set Neovim as a default editor during the installation (Git has a test feature to make sure your editor is working even during installation)
2. in `$home` find `.gitconfig` and add the path to your editor, but use two escapes `\\` when there is space, e.g. `C:/Program\\ Files/...`

Comment: I think the issue has to do with `tty`. I'm experiencing the same issue but reinstalling git bash doesn't seem to work. However, running `winpty nvim` does

Comment: I experienced the same issue and made an alias for nvim wrapping 'winpty nvim', and it works on my Git for Windows installation. Many thanks!

Comment: I also wrapped some commands with `winpty {command}` - which is very handy. But still - don't like that I had to do that in the first place ... :(

Answer (score 2):

Create an alias by editing the `.bashrc` file with the following command:

```bash
vi .bashrc
```

Then create an alias by placing the following text into the editor:

```
alias nvim="winpty nvim"
```

Go to normal mode by pressing `ESC` then save the file with `:wq` command. The final step is to apply the changes using this command:

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: Welcome and thank you for posting an answer. Could you please provide a reference regarding the behavior of `echo \ `? BTW, an alternative would be to put the alias in `.bashrc` using an editor. I'd recommend a vi clone.

Comment: I agree, using an editor is a less hacky way to create an alias. I am going to edit the answer that uses the `vi` command.

Comment: I wouldn't say "hacky"... but I'd want to stay in control of my `.bashrc`. Actually, I'm still curious about the `echo \ ` thing. Man pages say nothing about it. If anything, `\a` should be interpreted as BELL as far as I've seen. When I tried, the leading backslash did not seem to do anything.

Comment: Well, it was a trial-and-error kind of thing. First, I started the echo command with `\ ` (inspired by the markdown syntax) character. Then I saw that it adds a space to the config file therefore I got rid of it. So I ended with the weird: `echo \alias...` command that I do not really like in retrospect.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You're welcome! I also thank you for reviewing and commenting so the post reached a better quality.